# Product code looks like abcd2343, how to split by letters and numbers?

Tags: python, string, split

I have a list of product codes in a text file, on each line is the product code that looks like:

> abcd2343 abw34324 abc3243-23A

So it is **letters** followed by **numbers** and **other characters**.

I want to **split** on the **first occurrence of a number**.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

```
import re
s='abcd2343 abw34324 abc3243-23A'
re.split('(\d+)',s)

> ['abcd', '2343', ' abw', '34324', ' abc', '3243', '-', '23', 'A']
```

Or, if you want to split on the first occurrence of a digit:

```
re.findall('\d*\D+',s)
> ['abcd', '2343 abw', '34324 abc', '3243-', '23A']
```

---

- `\d+` matches 1-or-more digits.
- `\d*\D+` matches 0-or-more digits followed by 1-or-more non-digits.
- `\d+|\D+` matches 1-or-more digits *or* 1-or-more non-digits.

Consult [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) for more about Python's regex syntax.

---

`re.split(pat, s)` will split the string `s` using `pat` as the delimiter.  If `pat` begins and ends with parentheses (so as to be a "capturing group"), then `re.split` will return the substrings matched by `pat` as well. For instance, compare:

```
re.split('\d+', s)
> ['abcd', ' abw', ' abc', '-', 'A']   # <-- just the non-matching parts

re.split('(\d+)', s)
> ['abcd', '2343', ' abw', '34324', ' abc', '3243', '-', '23', 'A']  # <-- both the non-matching parts and the captured groups
```

In contrast, `re.findall(pat, s)` returns only the parts of `s` that match `pat`:

```
re.findall('\d+', s)
> ['2343', '34324', '3243', '23']
```

Thus, if `s` ends with a digit, you could avoid ending with an empty string by using `re.findall('\d+|\D+', s)` instead of `re.split('(\d+)', s)`:

```
s='abcd2343 abw34324 abc3243-23A 123'

re.split('(\d+)', s)
> ['abcd', '2343', ' abw', '34324', ' abc', '3243', '-', '23', 'A ', '123', '']

re.findall('\d+|\D+', s)
> ['abcd', '2343', ' abw', '34324', ' abc', '3243', '-', '23', 'A ', '123']
```

Comment: If you use '(\d+)', and a digit is the last character of the string, the last entry in the list will be an empty string. How do we avoid that?

Comment: IIUC, you could use `re.findall('(\d+|\D+)', 'abcd2343 abw34324 abc3243-23')`, which returns `['abcd', '2343', ' abw', '34324', ' abc', '3243', '-', '23']`.

Comment: Hello, how can I apply this to a whole column? My column "Product" is in the form "-8937ADF"  and I want to create two columns in the same dataframe containing "-8937" and "ADF" respectively.

Answer (score 9):

This function handles float and negative numbers as well.

```
def separate_number_chars(s):
    res = re.split('([-+]?\d+\.\d+)|([-+]?\d+)', s.strip())
    res_f = [r.strip() for r in res if r is not None and r.strip() != '']
    return res_f
```

For example:

```
utils.separate_number_chars('-12.1grams')
> ['-12.1', 'grams']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

m = re.match(r"(?P<letters>[a-zA-Z]+)(?P<the_rest>.+)$",input)

m.group('letters')
m.group('the_rest')
```

This covers your corner case of abc3243-23A and will output `abc` for the letters group and 3243-23A for `the_rest`

Since you said they are all on individual lines you'll obviously need to put a line at a time in `input`

Answer (score 1):

```
def firstIntIndex(string):
    result = -1
    for k in range(0, len(string)):
        if (bool(re.match('\d', string[k]))):
            result = k
            break
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

To partition on the first digit

```
parts = re.split('(\d.*)','abcd2343')      # => ['abcd', '2343', '']
parts = re.split('(\d.*)','abc3243-23A')   # => ['abc', '3243-23A', '']
```

So the two parts are always parts[0] and parts[1].

Of course, you can apply this to multiple codes:

```
>>> s = "abcd2343 abw34324 abc3243-23A"
>>> results = [re.split('(\d.*)', pcode) for pcode in s.split(' ')]
>>> results
[['abcd', '2343', ''], ['abw', '34324', ''], ['abc', '3243-23A', '']]
```

If each code is in an individual line then instead of `s.split( )` use `s.splitlines()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code it will work fine

```
import re
text = "MARIA APARECIDA 99223-2000 / 98450-8026"
parts = re.split(r' (?=\d)',text, 1)
print(parts)
```

Output:

['MARIA APARECIDA', '99223-2000 / 98450-8026']