# Split a string consisting of letters and numbers into parts

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string consisting of alternating strings of lower-cased letters and numbers (integers or floats), which is of arbitrary length, and I wish to split it into parts, each of maximal possible size, such that a part will consist of either a string or a (string representing a) number.

I don't need to regard special forms of numbers, such as exponents, hexadecimal, etc.; just simple floating point or an integer.

A few examples:

```
>>> split("")
()
>>> split("p")
('p',)
>>> split("2")
('2',)
>>> split("a2b3")
('a', '2', 'b', '3')
>>> split("a2.1b3")
('a', '2.1', 'b', '3')
>>> split("a.1b3")
('a', '.1', 'b', '3')
```

However, the following calls should raise some error:

```
>>> split(3)
>>> split("a0.10.2")
>>> split("ab.c")
```

My first attempt was using `re.split`. However, this attempt is quite naive, and it does not save the delimiters, in case I make these letters:

```
>>> re.split("[a-z]", "a.1b3")
['', '.1', '3']
```

My second attempt was using `itertools.groupby`. The problem is that it does not care about the form of the number, so, for example:

```
>>> islowalpha = labmda s: str.isalpha(s) and str.islower(s)
>>> [''.join(g) for _, g in itertools.groupby("a0.10.2b", islowalpha)]  # should raise
['a', '0.10.2', 'b']
```

**Note:** I don't care about the form of the output, as long as it is iterable.

**Note:** I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572387/splitting-letters-from-numbers-within-a-string), but I could not adapt the solution to my problem. The main difference is that I need to allow only acceptable numbers, and not a simple list of digits and points.

Comment: What is wrong with `"a0.10.2"` and why it is different from `"a2.1b3"`?

Comment: Since `0.10.2` is not a number; and it is also not an alternating substring of numbers and lower-cased strings.

Comment: Got it, missed 'alternating' restriction.

Answer (score 4):

```
import re

def split_gen(x):
    for f, s in re.findall(r'([\d.]+)|([^\d.]+)', x):
        if f:
            float(f)
            yield f
        else:
            yield s

def split(x):
    '''
    >>> split("")
    ()
    >>> split("p")
    ('p',)
    >>> split("2")
    ('2',)
    >>> split("a2b3")
    ('a', '2', 'b', '3')
    >>> split("a2.1b3")
    ('a', '2.1', 'b', '3')
    >>> split("a.1b3")
    ('a', '.1', 'b', '3')
    >>> split(3)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    TypeError: expected string or buffer
    >>> split("a0.10.2")
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0.10.2'
    >>> split("ab.c")    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    ValueError: could not convert string to float: '.'
    '''
    return tuple(split_gen(x))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit of play with `re.sub` and `itertools.cycle`:

```
def split(s):
    res = []

    def replace(matchobj):
        res.append(matchobj.group(0))
        return ''

    letter = re.compile('^([a-z]+)')
    number = re.compile('^(\.\d|\d+\.\d+|\d+)')

    if letter.match(s):
        c = itertools.cycle([letter, number])
    else:
        c = itertools.cycle([number, letter])

    for op in c:
        mods = op.sub(replace, s)
        if len(s) == len(mods):
            return
        elif not mods:
            return res
        s = mods
```

The basic idea - create two alternating `re` patterns and try to match the input string with them.

A demo with some of your examples:

```
>>> split("2")
['2']
>>> split("a2b3")
['a', '2', 'b', '3']
>>> split("a.1b3")
['a', '.1', 'b', '3']
>>> split("a0.10.2")
>>> split("ab.c")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the premise of the your question is plausible.  How can you distinguish floats from an arbitrary string?  There are a lot of ways to interpret.  For example,
    0.10.2 
This can mean 0.1, 0.2. or 0, .10, .2
what if the number is 
    27.6734.98?
You need to specify what kind of number and what format it will be first.  Ex: every number only has one digit beside decimals.

Comment: I don't agree with your criticism. I explicitly mentioned that strings like `27.6734.98` should raise an error, as they do not consist of *alternating* lower-cased alpha strings and number strings.

Comment: Sorry if it sounds like criticism.  What I mean is that what if the number part is something like '27.6734.98'.  So a complete example input could be like 'ab27.6734.98h'.

Answer (score -1):

```
import re

string = 'a.2b3c4.5d'

REG_STR = r'([a-zA-Z])|(\.\d+)|(\d+\.\d+)|(\d+)'
matches = [m.group() for m in re.finditer(REG_STR, string) if re.finditer(REG_STR, string)]
```

Comment: Erk, not reading things. Regex should be `'([a-zA-Z])|(\.\d+)|(\d+\.\d+)|(\d+)'`

Comment: Edit your post with the answer you propose folks use.