# How do I create a new column in a csv file using Pandas, and add data depending on the values in those columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am trying to create a column using data from another column based on part of the information of that column, For example I have a list of devices:

```
 devicename        make     devicevalue
 switch1           cisco        0
 switch1-web100    netgear      0  
 switch10          cisco        0
 switch23          cisco        1
 switch31-web200   netgear      0
 switch31          cisco        1
 switch40          cisco        1
```

The column needs have 2 variables:

- If `make == netgear` (set to 0)
- If `devicename` end in 20 or greater (set to 1, otherwise set to 0)
- Alternatively, instead of also looking at the make the `devicename` could be filtered by `web` too.

I am using Pandas to open CSV file, make the edits (for some other columns) then save it, but I am having difficulty with this bit.

This is where I have gotten to, but I know it doesn't work but I've got a bit lost and I'm quite new to Python:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df['devicevalue'] = df.devicename
    if 'netgear' in df.name df.set_value '0'
    if str.endswith > 20 df.set_value '0'
    else if df.set_value '1'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['devicename', 'make'])
df.loc[0] = ['switch1', 'cisco']
df.loc[1] = ['switch1-web100', 'netgear']
df.loc[2] = ['switch10', 'cisco']
df.loc[3] = ['switch23', 'cisco']
df.loc[4] = ['switch31-web200', 'netgear']
df.loc[5] = ['switch31', 'cisco']
df.loc[6] = ['switch40', 'cisco']


def get_number_suffix(devicename: str) -> int:
    """
    This function looks at the last several characters, and extracts
    the last n contiguous digits, and returns as an integer.
    :param devicename:
    :return:
    """
    i = 1
    while i < len(devicename) and devicename[-i:].isnumeric():
        i += 1

    return int(devicename[-(i-1):])


def compute_devicevalue(row) -> int:
    """
    This function computes the devicevalue based on the criteria:
    If make = netgear (set to 0)
    If devicename end in 20 or greater (set to 1, otherwise set to 0)
    :param row:
    :return:
    """

    if 'netgear' in row['make']:
        return 0
    if 20 <= get_number_suffix(row['devicename']):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0


df['devicevalue'] = df.apply(compute_devicevalue, axis=1)
print(df.head(7))
```

Comment: thank you for the reply,

I'll see if i can make this work, do I need to import each line item in the top portion?
As I have about 9000 records that I have to export from another tool, then process and add this new column in

Comment: No, no. I only did that for the example. You should definitely use 'read_csv' as in your question.

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you, I had to add another if statement to remove a model variant as well, but I was able to add it easily now that I could see how to create it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are having trouble working through the data. Here is how I would approach this. Use a for loop to cycle through the different elements in each column, then use logic on each of those as you cycle through. [This question previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340081/product-code-looks-like-abcd2343-what-to-split-by-letters-and-numbers) found a great way to split the letters from the numbers; they explained it better than I can.

```
Make   = ['cisco', 'netgear', 'cisco', 'cisco', 'netgear']
Number = ['switch1', 'switch1-web100', 'switch10', 'switch23', 'switch31-web200']
newcol = []
for i, j in enumerate(Make):
    if i == 'netgear':
        if int(re.split('(\d+)',Number[j])[-1]) > 20:
            newcol.append(1)
        else:
            newcol.append(0)
    else:
        newcol.append(0)
```

Comment: A broadcasting approach would probably scale better.

Comment: You are right, that would be faster. Good thinking!

Comment: Thanks for your reply/help even though I didn't use this method