# How to separate number and ascii character from string?

Tags: python

Let me keep it simple,
I have a string that I want it from `"10fo22baar"` into `["1022","fobaar"]` or `["10","fo","22","baar"]`
Is there a way to do something like that in Python 3 or 2?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340081/product-code-looks-like-abcd2343-what-to-split-by-letters-and-numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part 1:** You can use `filter` with `str.isdigit()` to filter numeric characters as:

```
>>> my_str = "10fo22baar"
>>> ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, my_str))
'1022'
```

To get non-numeric, you can use `itertools.filterfalse()`:

```
>>> from itertools import filterfalse

>>> ''.join(filterfalse(str.isdigit, my_str))
'fobaar'

# OR, for older python versions, use list comprehension:
# ''.join(c for c in my_str if not c.isdigit())
```

Store above values in `list` to get list of your desired format.

Alternatively, you can also use [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to filter out digits and alphabets into separate lists as:

```
import re
my_str = "10fo22baar"

# - To extract digits, use expressions as "\d+"
# - To extract alphabets, use expressions as "[a-zA-Z]+"

digits = ''.join(re.findall('\d+', my_str))
# where `digits` variable will hold string:
#    '1022'

alphabets = ''.join(re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+', my_str))
# where `alphabets` variable will hold string:
#    'fobaar'

# Create your desired list from above variables:
# my_list = [digits, alphabets]
```

You can simplify above logic in one-line as:

```
my_regex = ['\d+', '[a-zA-Z]+']

my_list = [''.join(re.findall(r, my_str)) for r in my_regex]
# where `my_list` will give you:
#   ['1022', 'fobaar']
```

---

**Part 2:** You can use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to get your second desired format of list with digits and alphabets grouped together maintaining the ordwe in single list as:

```
from itertools import groupby

my_list = [''.join(x) for _, x in groupby(my_str, str.isdigit)]
# where `my_list` will give you:
#    ['10', 'fo', '22', 'baar']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to make a for loop. Like this:

```
str = "10fo22baar"
nums = []
chars = []

for char in str:
    try:
        int(char)
        nums.append(char)
    except ValueError:
        chars.append(char)


sep = ["".join(nums), "".join(chars)]
print(sep)
```

Output would be: ['1022', 'fobaar']

Comment: I’d recommend a more robust approach then replying on a try/except block.  There are built in methods to help make this code more explicit and efficient. (Think: Zen)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple and easy to understand solution.

```
mystring = '10fo22baar'
nums = []
chars = []

for char in mystring:

    if char in ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8''9']:

        nums.append(char)
    else:

        chars.append(char)
```

How it works:

1. We start with `mystring` set to the string we want to read.
2. We define two new lists for our numbers and regular chars.
3. We loop through each char in `mystring`.
4. If the current char of the loop iteration is a number, we append it to the number list.
5. If it's not a number, it must be a normal char. We append it to `chars`.
6. That's it

Comment: Sure. I'll edit my main answer so future users can see the explanation clearly.

Comment: I believe OP has edited the original question. I think he explicitly listed an acceptable output being two strings with the string chars sorted between the two.

Comment: @WinXPdev Can you confirm? I'm not sure how to view the question history, and I remember explicitly choosing to bother answering because it was solvable with a loop and conditional string appending.

Comment: I think he explicitly listed an acceptable output being two strings and edited the original question.

Comment: I just confirmed that the question was not edited. I fixed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using string methods:

```
s = "10fo22baar"
num = ""
string = ""
for char in s:
    if char.isnumeric():
        num += str(char) 
    else:
        string += str(char)
print(num, string)
```

Gives ('1022', 'fobaar')

Answer (score 0):

1-First, we would have to do a for to go through the entire string.

2-After that to check if the character is a number or not, we could use two methods:

string.isnumeric()
or
string.isalpha()

3-After checking, we separate the characters into lists and format them to our liking.

Our code looks like this:

```
myString = '10fo22baar'
charString = []
charNum = []

for char in myString:
    if char.isnumeric():
        charNum.append(char)
    else:
        charString.append(char)

myString = [''.join(charNum), ''.join(charString)] 
print(myString)
```