# Python: Parsing Excel cell notation to retreive column and row separately

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Since I'm using Pandas' read_excel function, I would need to split a cell reference or cell range provided as a string to be able to populate the usecols and skiprows attributes of read_excel. So for instance:

```
user enters: C6
parse it: usecols="C", skiprows="6"

user enters: AA62
parse it: usecols="AA", skiprows="62"

user enters: A5:C5
parse it: usecols="A,C", skiprows="5"
```

Any ideas on the best way to achieve this? I'm okay to not use pandas' read_excel if there are other libraries that can make it easier to read excel files using the cell notation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions (Regex) to achieve that. You’ll essentially need to import the library and then provide a pattern to have the command recognize the letters from the numbers. As an example:

```
import re

user_input = “AA62”

parsed_user_input = re.split('(\d+)',user_input)
```

> [‘AA’, ‘62’]

I’d also recommend this thread for further patterns: [Product code looks like abcd2343, what to split by letters and numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340081/product-code-looks-like-abcd2343-what-to-split-by-letters-and-numbers)