# Any way to split strings in Python at the place were an integer appears?

Tags: python, string, split

I webscraped some data but it jammed it all into one place, so I'm trying to split a list of strings and the strings are composed out of string characters and out of numbers. I want to split them the moment a number appears and make myself a data table out of that.

Imagine there is a list strings:

```
string0 = 'string123' ; string1 = 'a12' ; string2 = 'bob69'....
```

Has anyone have got any ideas how I can do that?

Comment: Use a regular expression to match the letters in one capture group and integer in the second capture group.

Comment: `([a-z]+)(\d+)`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Product code looks like abcd2343, what to split by letters and numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340081/product-code-looks-like-abcd2343-what-to-split-by-letters-and-numbers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using regex? i.e., the re package in python, combined with the split method? Something like this could work:

```
import re
string = 'string01string02string23string4string500string'

strlist = re.split('(\d+)', string)
print(strlist)
['string', '01', 'string', '02', 'string', '23', 'string', '4', 'string', '500', 'string']
```

You would then need to combine every other element in the list in your case i think, so something like this:

```
cmb = [i+j for i,j in zip(strlist[::2], strlist[1::2])]
print(cmb)

['string01', 'string02', 'string23', 'string4', 'string500']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split using a regex with only a lookbehind and lookahead (see `re` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for reference):

```
import re
re.split('(?<=\D)(?=\d)', string0)
```

output: `['string', '123']`

*NB. if you want to split on any change from non-number to number and conversely:*

```
re.split('(?<=\D)(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=\D)', 'abc123abc123')

## OR

re.findall('(\D+|\d+)', 'abc123abc123')
```

output: `['abc', '123', 'abc', '123']`

Answer (score 0):

Consider use regex with more control: how much digits to parse, for example 1 or 2:

```py
s = "of-r1-gi1-1-333 lala22l _22"
pattern = re.compile("((?<!\d)\d{1,2}(?!\d))")
pattern.split(s)
# ['of-r', '1', '-gi', '1', '-', '1', '-333 lala', '22', 'l _', '22', '']
```

Even more control:

```py
filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), pattern.split(s))
# ['1', '1', '1', '22', '22']
```