# Is there a way to get strings and integers within a variable seperately in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, input

If i take a input like below

```
input = "100 hours"
```

how can i take integers and strings seperately from the variable and assign them to two seperate variables

Comment: You will find the *re* module very helpful. Or, if the pattern in your string is always as per your example (i.e., a number followed by some text) then you can just use *string.split()*. Also, don't use names of built-in functions as variable names

Comment: You can try this 
number, string = input.split()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Product code looks like abcd2343, how to split by letters and numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340081/product-code-looks-like-abcd2343-how-to-split-by-letters-and-numbers)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regex with two groups to do that.
A group is a part of a regex pattern enclosed in parentheses `()` metacharacter

For example:

```
import re

target_string = "100 hours"

# two groups enclosed in separate ( and ) bracket
result = re.search(r"([0-9]+).*([a-zA-Z]+)", target_string)

# Extract matching values of all groups
print(result.groups())

# Output ('100', 'hours')
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `split` along with tuple syntax here:

```py
input = "100 hours"
(num, units) = input.split()
print(num)    # 100
print(units)  # hours
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following solution using regex:

```
import re 

input_string = "100 hours"
# substitute all the characters and spaces with an empty string
only_numbers = re.sub(r"[a-zA-Z ]", "", input_string) 
# substitute all the numbers with an empty string
only_characters = re.sub(r"[0-9]", "", input_string) 

print(only_numbers) # prints "100"
print(only_characters) # prints " hours"
```

The nice thing about this solution is that it will work no matter how the numbers and characters are distributed throughout the input string. You can tweak the regex in each statement to match your specific needs.