# Return values from dictionary?

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I am having a lot of trouble understanding this problem.  I need to enter a string in the format of 2X+4Y (e.g number + letter, can be two letters such as HE, +number + letter

if the input value is 2X+4Y Then return the value should be x2y4. The values need to be distinct and need to match the dictionary symbol and be positive integers.

```
#enter a string in form xA + yB +zC
#x, y, z are postive integers
#A,B,C are distinct symbols of elements (2H + 1O + 1C)

symbol = {"H":1,"He":4, "Li":7, "Be":9, "B":11, "C":12, "N":14, "O":16, "F":19, "Ne":20}





def stoi_coefficent(final_input): # this will only work when letter inputs are 'H', 'O' rather than 'HE'
    output=[]
    for i in final_input:
            output+= i[1::2]
            output+=i[0: :2]
    print(output)
    return output

def Convert(output):
    output_dct = {output[i]: output[i + 1] for i in range(0, len(output), 2)}
    print(output_dct)
    return output_dct


def check_if_in_symbol(output):
    active = True
    while active:
        for i in output:
              if i not in symbol or i not in numbers:
                    print('enter another symbol or number')
        else:
              active=False
              continue

a = (stoi_coefficent(final_input))
print(output)
print(Convert(output))
b = (check_if_in_symbol(a))

while True:
     user_input = input('\nEnter a string in the format of xA + yB + zC: ') # "4Ne + 1Be + 2Li"
     split_str = user_input.replace(" ", "").split("+")

     try:
          pairs = [str_parser(userstr) for userstr in split_str]
          check_elements(pairs)
     except ValueError:
          continue

     final_result = swap(pairs)
     print(f"Final Result: {final_result}")
     break
```

I have tried various other ideas but I think I need to make the input into a dictionary. But how do I make a dictionary when the split function makes a list in the format of [2x,4y]
and how would I use a comparative operator when the numbers and letters are one list item?

Comment: a = (stoi_coefficent(final_input))
print(Convert(a))
b = (check_if_in_symbol(a))

Apologies, I used the incorrect list in the above.  I can now get a dictionary but not sure about the next steps

Comment: To split the numbers from the letters you could use the `re` package like in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340081/product-code-looks-like-abcd2343-how-to-split-by-letters-and-numbers

Comment: What is the output that you want in the case that the user enters more than two values, i.e., if "2X + 4Y" should be "x24y", what should "2X + 4Y + 3Z" return?

Comment: it should return the letters and numbers swapped as a final out.  E.g 2HE +20 +1H (HE2O2H1)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your recent comments, you should edit your question to be something like this:

### Question

I want to take input from the user in the form of `xA + yB + zC`. 
And I want an output like this `AxByCz`.

They should be able to enter any number of combinations. 
If x, y, or z are 1, I want to exclude them.

For example: 
`4Ne + 1Be + 2Li` 
`Ne4BeLi2`

If the first number of every element isn't a positive integer or the element isn't a key in the SYMBOLS dict below, I want to print an error message and have the user try again.

```
SYMBOLS = {"H":1,"He":4, "Li":7, "Be":9, "B":11, "C":12, "N":14, "O":16, "F":19, "Ne":20}
```

Here's what I tried:

```
My code here
```

Problem I'm having here.

### Answer

If you can't use other modules, you'll need to make your own string parser.

There are many different ways to do it, but here's one way, including a loop that starts over whenever the user enters invalid input:

```py
SYMBOLS = {"H":1,"He":4, "Li":7, "Be":9, "B":11, "C":12, "N":14, "O":16, "F":19, "Ne":20}

def str_parser(userstr):
     if not userstr:
          print("Empty string detected. Please try again.")
          raise ValueError()

     first_char = userstr[0]
     if not first_char.isdigit():
          print(f"First digit of element must be a positive integer: {userstr}. Please try again.")
          raise ValueError()

     index = 1
     lastindex = 1
     digits = []
     char = first_char
     while char.isdigit():
          digits.append(char)
          try:
               next_char = userstr[index]
          except IndexError:
               break
          else:
               char = next_char
               lastindex = index
               index += 1

     coefficent = "".join(digits)
     return coefficent, userstr[lastindex:]

def check_elements(pairs):
     for _, element in pairs:
          if element.capitalize() not in SYMBOLS:
               print(f"Element not recognized: {element}. Please try again.")
               raise ValueError()

def swap(pairs):
     final_str = ""
     for coeff, element in pairs:
          if int(coeff) < 2:
               final_str += element
          else:
               final_str += element+coeff
     return final_str

while True:
     user_input = input('\nEnter a string in the format of xA + yB + zC: ') # "4Ne + 1Be + 2Li"
     split_str = user_input.replace(" ", "").split("+")

     try:
          pairs = [str_parser(userstr) for userstr in split_str]
          check_elements(pairs)
     except ValueError:
          continue

     final_result = swap(pairs)
     print(f"Final Result: {final_result}")
     break

# Ne4BeLi2
```

Comment: Ah this is really helpful! Unfortunately I am not allowed to use any packages other than Math. 

The second part of the question is checking if the input is in the list of symbols and adding the atomic weights together, hence the symbols dictionary

Comment: @Amandasissons Ah, that's rough. See my edit above.

Comment: Thank you! Really appreciate it! I am just unsure how I would print the final output of H23H? Do I create a separate list and do a loop with a conditional to check if it isdigit and add it to index[1]?

Comment: I'm confused, I thought your final output was the addition all the atomic weights together, why do you need to print "H23H"?

Comment: That's a very different question than the one you asked. You should edit your question to make it clearer. I've edited my post to include how I would edit the question as well as a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the input as you do (`user_input.split('+')`), then apply this to each element in the list to split numbers from letters.

[Product code looks like abcd2343, how to split by letters and numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340081/product-code-looks-like-abcd2343-how-to-split-by-letters-and-numbers)

You then have the symbols and numbers which you can check for validity separately.